# cc1plus: "-Wno-unused-result" error

Tags: c++, cmake

i want to compile project, but i have error:

```
[  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/task2.dir/main.cpp.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/task2.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/task2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

OSX Mountain Lion , gcc version is (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.1_3) 4.8.1

Makefile done by CMake 2.8-12

Can you help me, plz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using (either directly or via a makefile) the command line option `-Wno-unused-result` with (I presume) the gcc compiler. However, gcc does not recognise that option, which (I presume again) aims at suppressing warnings about not using results of a computation. With gcc you should instead use the option `-Wno-unused-value`.

Note, however, that (like almost all warnings) **this is a useful warning, which shouldn't be suppressed or ignored**. If the result of a computation is not used, the whole computation may be redundant and could be omitted without effect. In fact, the compiler may optimize it away, *if* it can be sure that it has no side effects. For example

```
int foo1(double&x)   // pass by reference: we can modify caller's argument
{
  int r=0;
  // do something to x and r
  return r;
}

int foo2(double x)   // pass by value: make a local copy of argument at caller
{
  return foo1(x);    // only modifies local variable x
}

void bar(double&x)
{
  int i=foo1(x);     // modifies x
  int j=foo2(x);     // does not modify x
  // more code, not using i or j
}
```

Here, `i` and `j` in `bar()` are not used. However, optimizing the call to `foo1()` away is not allowed, since that call also affects `x`, while the call `foo2()` has no side effects. So, to avoid the warning, simply *ignore* the unused result and *avoid* unneccary compuations

```
void bar(double&x)
{
  foo1(x);  // ignoring any value returned by foo1()
            // foo2(x) did not affect x, so can be removed
  // more code
}
```

Comment: oh, it compiles!! Thanks a lot, but there is another problem: i cant change cmakelists, because this project will be checked on another laptop.

Comment: @user2897535 That's another problem for another question. If this answer solved your initial problem, please accept it (green tick).

Comment: Please enable all warnings

Comment: @EdHeal Most, but not *all warnings* are useful. For example, with `clang++ -std=c++11 -Weverthing` you get some useless warnings such as `-Wc++98-compat` which will complain about any C++11 feature. (I think `clang++` should suppress this warning if `-std=c++11`.)

Comment: @EdHeal this must be because you're still using C++98.

Comment: @Walter - So you think that the person who wrote the compiler bungs in warning for no reason. They must be bored

Comment: @EdHeal Well, every warning has its use *in some context*, but not in every context. Say, I'm developing code in C++ using the most recent standard, then backward compatibility to an old standard is of no concern and the respective warning annoying at best.